# Not Receiving Push Notification when app is killed on android device

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, push-notification

I am currently working with RN0.44 , everything working fine on emulator , however on physical android device i am only able to receive push notification (remote) when app is running or at least it is in background, but when i kill the app i am unable to receive notifications.

I have also checked the settings for my app but no luck.

I am using this package [react-native-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-notifications)

I have also raised an issue at [github](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/151)

Any help is appreciated.